# Problema con funcion basica

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola Estoy iniciandome en Python y tengo un problema con un ejercicio de una función que en principio parece muy básica, pero no entiendo porque no devuelve lo que corresponde. Basicamente lo que busca es invertir una cadena, y para ello creo una lista invertida, pero no entiendo porque no guarda bien el orden.

```
def inverso():
    print("Esta función imprime la cadena inversa.")
    print("")
    print("Introduce una cadena de texto o números: ")
    cadena = input()
    longitud = len(cadena)
    ciclo = 0
    lista = list()
    for c in cadena:
        i = longitud - 1 - ciclo
        lista.insert(i,c)
        ciclo += 1

    cadena_inversa = "".join(lista)  
    print(cadena_inversa)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que entiendas el problema vayamos a un caso básico, sea la lista:

```
lista = [0]
```

y ahora insertamos en la posicion 8 el valor de 1:

```
lista.insert(8, 1)
```

por lo que obtenemos:

```
[0, 1]
```

y nos preguntamos:

**¿Hemos insertado en la posición 8 el valor de 1?**

Pues no, si insertas un valor en un índice mayor al máximo indice existente solo se añade al final, y eso es lo que sucede en tu caso, para observarlo mejor añádiré `print`s dentro del for:

```
...
for c in cadena:
    i = longitud - 1 - ciclo
    lista.insert(i,c)
    ciclo += 1
    print("lista.insert({},{}): {}".format(i, c, lista))
...
```

Y obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
Esta función imprime la cadena inversa.

Introduce una cadena de texto o números: 
1234567890
lista.insert(9,1): ['1']
lista.insert(8,2): ['1', '2']
lista.insert(7,3): ['1', '2', '3']
lista.insert(6,4): ['1', '2', '3', '4']
lista.insert(5,5): ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
lista.insert(4,6): ['1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '5']
lista.insert(3,7): ['1', '2', '3', '7', '4', '6', '5']
lista.insert(2,8): ['1', '2', '8', '3', '7', '4', '6', '5']
lista.insert(1,9): ['1', '9', '2', '8', '3', '7', '4', '6', '5']
lista.insert(0,0): ['0', '1', '9', '2', '8', '3', '7', '4', '6', '5']
0192837465
```

El comportamiento que señale mi ejemplo se ve hasta que la lista tiene la mitad del tamaño final, es decir, hasta que tiene el tamaño 5, y despues se va insertando pero no de la forma adecuada, asi que la lógica de inserción esta fallando.

Si queremos seguir usando tu lógica inicial la solución es insertar siempre en la posición 0:

```
...
for c in cadena:
    lista.insert(0,c)
...
```

Tambien hay formas sencillas sin usar for-loop:

- Usando *slice notation*:

  ```
  def inverso():
      print("Esta función imprime la cadena inversa.")
      print("")
      print("Introduce una cadena de texto o números: ")
      cadena = input()
      cadena_inversa = cadena[::-1]
      print(cadena_inversa) 
  inverso()
  ```
- Usando reversed:

  ```
  def inverso():
      print("Esta función imprime la cadena inversa.")
      print("")
      print("Introduce una cadena de texto o números: ")
      cadena = input()
      cadena_inversa = "".join(reversed(cadena))
      print(cadena_inversa) 
  inverso()
  ```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación. La verdad es que me han quedado claro tanto el método inicial que tenía dudas, como las dos alternativas propuestas. Un saludo.

Comment: @JorgeCantero si mi respuesta te ayudo a solucionar tu problema no olvides marcarla como correcta, si no sabes como hacerlo revisa el [tour], esa es la mejor forma de agradecer :)

Comment: Hecho!!. No controlo aun mucho el funcionamiento. Gracias de nuevo.